# Adding UIImageView as subview to an OpenGL ES 2.0 View

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

i've set up an OpenGL ES 2.0 View following this iPhone - tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial

Now I'm trying to paint on top of an image. I have already tried the following, but nothing did work:

- Adding an UIImageView as a subview of the OpenGL View
- Adding the UIImageView as a subview in the ViewController beneath the OpenGL View
- Painting the Image with OpenGL in the same context doesn't work either, mainly because the texture size is not a power of 2...

Both times only the OpenGL View was visible.

Comment: put the image view over top of the OpenGL view

Comment: from what i know you can't have a UIKit element inside the the openGL view or underneath it (openGL view is not transparent anyway), you have do draw it on top.

Comment: @KDaker - No, you can indeed have a UIView as a subview of a UIView that's displaying OpenGL ES content. I do it all the time. Something else must be going wrong in this case, because this should work just fine.

Comment: I also tried with putting UIImageView as subview of UIView displaying OpenGL ES content. But was not able to draw on that UIImageView. any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the image below OpenGL, you cannot add a `UIImageView` as a subview, it will be drawn on top of your render.
Drawing it as a texture on a rectangle will work (I actually use it in an application), but you must resize your image.
Placing the `UIImageView` beneath your OpenGL view also will work, but you have to tweak a few parameters first:

1. Make sure that `kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat` is `kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8`. This must be set in your `CAEAGLLayer`, by setting the property `drawableProperties`:

   ```
   CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
   eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                   kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                   kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8,
                                   kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                   nil];
   ```

   I think the right place for that is your `- (void)setupLayer`method.
2. Make sure that your `CAEAGLLayer.opaque` property is set to `NO` (again in `setupLayer`).
3. When you clear your buffer, clear it with a 0% alpha color, in such a way that the contents behind the GLView are visible:

   ```
   glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   ```
4. Consider enabling alpha blending if you plan to use multisample or to draw objects with alpha<1.

In my experience, anyway, keeping the GLView opaque and drawing the background with a texture is remarkably faster. Nothing that an iPhone 5 user would notice probably, but on an old iPhone 3G the frames per second increased significantly.